# Showing a function is bigger than another one under some settings

Tags: inequality

I've 2 functions:

$$f_1(p, h) = \frac{1}{p - p(1-h)^{17+16c_0})},$$
and
$$f_2(p, h) = \frac{1}{ph}.$$
Further, I've the following constraints on variables:
$ 0 < p \leq 1, 0 < h < 1$ and $c_0$ is a constant with $c_0 > 1$.

I've the intuition that $f_1 > f_2$ under these settings. However, I'm not sure how to prove it. Also, if my intuition is incorrect, how can I at least find the intervals in which  $f_2 > f_1$ ?

Comment: Is the formula for $f_1$ correct?  I ask because I don't understand why you have left $1-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ah yes, they will simply cancel out

Comment: And after doing that, pull out a factor of $p$ and you are left with a statement that only involves $h$.

Comment: You posted essentially this question a while ago, then deleted it while I was typing an answer.  That does not motivate me to answer again.

Comment: It was because I made some errors in that. I've went over everything once again and reposted it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac {f_2}{f_1}=\frac {1-(1-h)^{17+16c_0}}h$ so the value of $p$ does not matter.  We can then write $(1-h)^{17+16c_0} \gt 1-h(17+16c_0)$ by the binomial theorem so as long as $17+16c_0 \gt 1$ you will have $f_2 \gt f_1$